# What mstrConnection should I use on a webpage to access local SQL Server Express (localhost\SQLEXPRESS)?

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

Would the following suffice?

```
Dim mstrConnection As String =
  "workstation id=COMPUTER;packet size=4096;data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;
    integrated security=false;user id=x309-PC\x309;password=abc"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get away with a simpler connection string like the following:

> Data Source=(local)\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

You also need to make sure in the SQL server security logins you have both mapped the user to a SQL login as well as given the user rights to the database you are interacting with. You can download [MS SQL management studio express 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B) to view and set these settings.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what would be the Initial Catalog? i see 4 databases after initial installation - master, model, msdb, tempdb. Should I use "master" as my initial catalog? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use whatever database it is you are trying to query data from. The Master DB contains metadata about the SQL server instance itself, so I doubt you want that. Try creating a test database and setting your initial catalog to that. Create some tables and populate them with some data then just select it out and write it to the console or HTTP out.

Comment: I'm not following, I have created a table under Databases\System Databases\Master\Tables\tblTest

Comment: It's probably not the best option to create test tables in the Master database. That is reserved for SQL server specific metadata. Try creating a new database in management studio and creating your test table under that DB. Right click on "Databases" under your SQL connection in the studio and select "New Database".

Comment: got it, this time the table is here Databases\test\Tables\dbo.tblTest
Should my Initial Catalog be "Test"?

Comment: initial catalog should be "test" based on your comment. Remember to create the login and set the permissions on the database for that user too.

Comment: i did that, but the webpage is still showing me Login failure. I've double check that the owner of "test" is x309-PC\x309, but I didn't set a password to it (i'm using my Windows login password instead because x309-PC\x309 is my windows Login) Thanks!

Comment: Under the security folder of the SQL server (not the database) you should have the user "x309-PC\x309" listed as a user and that user should have windows authentication selected under the first page of its properties. Then under the User Mapping section of the user's properties, the "test" database should show you the users mapping to db_owner. If all that looks correct, look at the SQL server logs after you get your login failure and see if the logs tell you a more specific reason for the failure. THe logs are accessible in the mgmt studio under Management\SQL Server Logs

Comment: All those looked correct. The error says: Query is select * from tblCustomers where username='johndoe' error is Login failed for user 'x309-PC\x309'.

Comment: would I need to specify that it's a Windows Authentication instead of a SQL Server authentication? Thanks!

Comment: check out this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997169/c-2008-sql-server-express-connection-string

Comment: I followed thread and added two slashes after local\\SQLExpress this time I get an Instance Error. I'm so close yet so far away =(