# Visual Studio 2013 DB Creation C# a network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing connection with sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi I have been going through threads with the same error but cannot find any solution with visual studio 2013. When I test the connection with the database only it works and I can enter the records manually. But when I try using the code below it gives me the above mentioned error. I created the database with SQL. The original Connection string is

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\fatimam\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\App_Data\BookingsDb.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

I suspect that my connection string in my code is not correctly formatted. I tried (LocalDB)\v11.0 and gives me the same error as well. when I run the program and it gets to the myDBconnection.Open(); then it goes to the Catch block. Could you please help me resolve this connection problem? Thank you

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
        using System.Data.Sql;
        using System.Data.OleDb;
        using System.Data.SqlClient;
        using System.Configuration;

        namespace BookingSystem
        {
        public partial class _Default : Page
        {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        int id = 65;
        string title = "Mr";
        string name = "Name";
        string surname = "Surname";
        string company = "Company";
        string address = "address";
        string city = "Cape town";
        string postal = "7764";
        string contact = "0829875";
        string email = "email";

        try
        {
            string myDBCon = "Data Source=." + "\\" + "SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:" + "\\" + "Users" + "\\" + "fatimam" + "\\" + "Documents" + "\\" + "Visual Studio 2013" + "\\" + "Projects" + "\\" + "BookingSystem" + "\\" + "BookingSystem" + "\\" + "App_Data" + "\\" + "BookingsDb.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            //Creating connection to the Database
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myDBconnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            //Adding the connection string to the connection
            myDBconnection.ConnectionString = myDBCon;
            //Opening Connection
            myDBconnection.Open();
            //Creating a string to hold the sql query
            string insertSqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Customer (customer_id, title, name,surname,company,address,city,postal_code,contact,email) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + title + "','" + name + "','" + surname + "','" + company + "','" + address + "','" + city + "','" + postal + "',,'" + contact + "','" + email + "')";
            //Create a command in C# to perform the sql Query
            SqlCommand myInsertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSqlQuery, myDBconnection);
            //Creating the process for performing the command
            SqlDataReader performCommand = myInsertCommand.ExecuteReader();
            //Executing the command or running the command
            performCommand.Read();
            //Closing the execution of the command
            performCommand.Close();
            //Closing the connection
            myDBconnection.Close();

        }

        catch (SqlException exp)
        {
            // Log what you need from here.
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Data could not be read", exp);
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Express 2012?  If you're using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, the default connection string may not be correct. Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: Why are you using a SQLExpress syntax for  a LocalDB instance?

Comment: I created the database by right clicking on App_Data folder->Add new item->then SQL Server Database. I a not sure how to check the Sql Server database on visual studio. SQLExpress I copied from an example we did in class. That is what the lecturer used when we did the example

Comment: @KenWhite - Care to post a link to go along with your helpful comment?

Comment: @KenWhite I have been trying for almost 12 hours..

Comment: @grambo25: Certainly. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+a+network+related+or+instance+specific+error

Comment: Double Click on the MDF file under App_data. This will open up the server explorer. Right-Click on the mdf in the Server explorer window and select properties. You'll see a "Connection String" Property. What does it say?

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\fatimam\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\App_Data\BookingsDb.mdf";Integrated Security=True

Comment: Ok then do this `string myDBCon = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\fatimam\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\App_Data\BookingsDb.mdf";Integrated Security=True"`  The `@` symbol stops you from having to escape the backslahes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your connection string `string myDBCon` just use single `\` and use `Server` keyword instead instead of `Data Source`. and at the end of your connection string you can use `Trusted_Connection=True;` instead of both `Integrated Security=True;` and `User Instance=True"`. And an other important thing is `YOURCOMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: I tried string myDBCon = "Server=" + "\\" + "FATIMA"+"\\"+"SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:" + "\\" + "Users" + "\\" + "fatimam" + "\\" + "Documents" + "\\" + "Visual Studio 2013" + "\\" + "Projects" + "\\" + "BookingSystem" + "\\" + "BookingSystem" + "\\" + "App_Data" + "\\" + "BookingsDb.mdf';Trusted_Connection=True;";
and I tried string myDBCon = Server=Fatima\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\fatimam\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\App_Data\BookingsDb.mdf";Trusted_Connection=True; Both gives red errors.

Comment: from the first one I tried removing also one \ and everything red underlined.

Comment: finally got it right.. string myDBCon = @"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\fatimam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\App_Data\BookingsDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

Answer (score 1):

Per the answer provided by user 'eu-ge-ne' here:

[c# 2008 SQL Server Express Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997169/c-sharp-2008-sql-server-express-connection-string)

The recommended solution would be to remove "Integrated Security=True" from your connection string, and optionally add "Persist Security Info=True;".

According to MSDN:

> Integrated Security - When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connect.  When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.